# Automating package compile process using GitHub API

Tags: linux, bash, github, debian

So, I'd like to create a shell script that automates the process of downloading a package, unzipping it, cd'ing into it, configuring it, and compiling it from source.

I have started with a simple script below:

`#!/bin/bash
PROJ=ruby
curl https://api.github.com/repos/$PROJ/$PROJ/tags -o $PROJ.json
cat $PROJ.json | grep -Po '(?<="name": ")[^"]*'`

This fetches the JSON file for the Ruby project, and returns the latest(?) tag name (e.g. ruby_2_3_1).

However, I am dumb, and I'd like to expand more on this script. I would like to:

- ignore any tags that don't include the word "ruby"
- only fetch the latest tag (in this example, 2_3_1)
- fetch the URL for tag 2_3_1 and download a tarball of the source code from that tag
- unzip the tarball (unless it detects that this tarball has been unzipped before)

The rest I can do on my own, as I'm fairly familiar with ./configure, make, make install, etc.

Hopefully this isn't *too* difficult. I'd prefer *not* to use jq (just standard regex), but if it happens to be easier with jq, I'll be fine either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At https://api.github.com/repos/ruby/ruby/tags I dont'see the word ruby in any tags name.

The tags are sorted by name in reverse order (the same as a `sort -nr`)

You can download and extract the latest tag ruby tarball by:

```
LAST_URL=`cat ruby.json | grep -Po '(?<="tarball_url": ")[^"]* | egrep -v [a-z]$ | head -1'
wget $LAST_URL && tar -xvzf `basename $LAST_URL`
```

Some notes:

- `egrep -v [a-z]$` filters out non ruby packages, not finishing in a number (es. *yarv_migration_base*)
- `head -1` takes the first tag (in the form vX_X_X) in a reverse order, the most recent

Comment: Hey, thanks! Apologies on the incorrect tag names, I didn't bother to recheck them. On another note, can I exclude the words "beta" or "preview" if they are in a tag?

Comment: np, without the ruby word in the tag name i filtered out not ruby version package by check if the tag fnishes with a number

Comment: The preview releases end up as "preview1" or "preview2". (On second thought, it would be nice to include previews... but I'd like to disable it just so I can.)

Comment: if you don't want previews you can `egrep v[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]$`. This matchs only tags finishing in vX_X_X

Comment: Hate to bother, but it seems like your script suddenly broke. I can't generate the tarball url and version name anymore :(. Mind looking at my script? https://ghostbin.com/paste/pugdo

Comment: It seems to be fine and the $URL and $TAG part of your script works for me. What error do you have?